# How to handle file syncing nightmare when developing cordova a plugin?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I would like to know if there are any best practises for how to organise files when developing a cordova plugin.

The problem is I have too many copies of the files and they are all in different structures, making it hard to debug and maintain a plugin.

When you install a plugin, say from github, the plugin is copied into the "plugins" folder in your project. It is also copied into the staging area in the "platforms" folder - java files somewhere in the src folder in platforms/android, objective C files in the platforms/ios, and javascript files are duplicated in both platforms under platform_www/plugins.

To debug the objective C part of my plugin I need to run my app (or a sample app) in xcode, debug and make changes. I may also make changes to the js file under ios platform at this point.

My question is what is the best way to sync the changes in objective C and js files from the app back to my plugin so that I can push it to github?

(I also need to keep the "plugins" folder in sync don't I, as this will overwrite my changed files on cordova build?). So with my app composed of several modified/developed plugins on two platforms the file syncing is a nightmare.

Anyone have any tips for development cycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way is to install the plugin from a local folder and using `--link` param.

When installing using `--link`, the changes you make in the Objective-C classes in Xcode will be done in the local plugin folder, so you won't have to propagate them. But it won't propagate the changes on the .js or plugin.xml files, you will have to manually copy them to the local folder.

Comment: I use a Beyond Compare session to sync changes to JS back to the local plugin folder

Comment: Excellent! This `--link` param sounds like the answer I was looking for! Also yes Beyond Compare is an essential part of my toolbox

Comment: This is really cool, much better than I expected (despite the js not being included - that would be ideal). Instead of 3 copies of the obj C files I now only have one. The `--link` parameter uses the file from the local folder and creates TWO aliases of that, one in the app project plugins folder (so cordova will have latest code) and one in the relevant platform folder (so xcode will have latest code).